# Registering for Event without Email Validation

Tags: permissions

How do I allow people to register without verifying their email address. CiviCRM seems to give 'permission denied' and even 'you don't have permission to view this event' until the email address is validated.

The setup is:

- LoginToboggan is used to enable the user to set a password.
- Immediate login is used.
- The user is given a 'registered' role.
- User signs up and receives 'you do not have permission to view this event'.
- Follows the email validation process and then can view the event.

An anonymous user can 'view the event'.

I want people to register for the event immediately as many people don't see their email and going offline means a lot forget where they are at.

Answer (score 1):

I set the LoginToboggan non-verified role to 'authenticated user'.

It is possible to set a permission for an 'authenticated user' but not a user with a specific role.